# HTML Select Value Attribute

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have this select fields with some options. PHP knows which should be selected.

I only see two options to do this:

1. On every option I do `<? if ($option == 'value of current option') echo 'selected=""'; ?>`
2. I set the value via JavaScript

I don't like neither of the possibilities. Why can't I just set `value="<?=$option?>` right in the select html tag?

Any other ideas how to do this?

Comment: What are you doing? `select` doesn't have a value.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. Though you can set a select's value with JS.

Comment: Create a new `option` element in the `select`, give it the value you want, then make it `selected`... or remove the `select` and make a `hidden` input with the same name. Not really clear what you are doing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply said: you can't. As you can see on the [W3Schools page on Select tags](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp), the *select* tag itself doesn't have any attributes which selects a certain option by default. Only the *option* tags do.

That being said, there are php libraries for forms which you can use. [Formidable](https://github.com/Gregwar/Formidable/blob/master/examples/select.php) is one of them. As the example points out, you should be able to just set the value afterwards. I don't have any personal experience with that library though.